# Quarkus build analytics not disabled in version 3.2.0.Final

Tags: redhat, quarkus

Are "Build analytics" (https://quarkus.io/guides/build-analytics) still opt-in in Quarkus 3.2.0.Final ?

It seems like our CI fails on Quarkus 3.2.0.Final projects because of build analytics: we are using maven helper plugin to read the project version number, and are getting as output (despite the options -q –DforceStdout):
`[warn] [Quarkus build analytics] Analytics remote config not received. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: (no message)`

In addition, I tried to disable them using the 2 solutions mentioned in the doc above:

- JSON File in `home/.redhat/io.quarkus.analytics.localconfig`
- Maven param `-Dquarkus.analytics.disabled=true`

But I still have the same problem, so it seems like it is still trying to get a remote config?

We didn't have this for previous versions of Quarkus, only for 3.2.0.

Comment: The build analytics logger is not router properly to the Maven logger, which I understand is being worked on, but filing an issue in the Quarkus issue tracker can't hurt. As for why Quarkus tries to download the build analytics config even if build analytics are disabled, I don't really know, but I would personally consider that a bug. Here's the Quarkus issue tracker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: Should defnitely not fail and yes it is optin. Please open issue with details.

Comment: yes, it's a bug if it tries to download the remote config and it's disabled.
But this is just a warning. The build is not failing. and analytics will not be sent if it's disabled.

Comment: thanks. I opened an issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34626  (fyi it is blocking our build, even though indirectly, because we are using the maven helper plugin to fetch project information, cannot get it because we get the log line instead, and our CI will not continue unless we have it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message has no impact on the build.

This is a bug. Remote config must only be obtained if user said yes already.

The fix: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/34641